# Help: Wordpress admin error, not able to login

Tags: php, wordpress, class

After updating wordpress to 3.1 my site stopped functioning. There was some functionality in the admin section of the site, but the site would blank out on random pages after setting changes. The front end of the site is somewhat functional. It would only seem to work when I have a maintenance plugin active, otherwise it blank out.

I finally got the site to work by using a backup version of my site before the update, but when I went into the admin section **I got a "Database Update" message** so thats what I did (I guess it's a new feature for 3.1). I updated the database, but after putting in my username and password in the admin login screen, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_blogs_of_user() in /home/content/html/drtv/wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php on line 18
```

Im pretty sure this has something to do with traces of the 3.1 version in the database, as the class-wp-admin-bar.php is being called.

Thanks for any help on this issue. This is a day long problem that is completely wrecking my brain. The bad part about it is that I need to put the site in maintenance mode because of some site errors and Im not able to because I can't get into the admin.

**Here is the link to the site:** [HERE](http://www.doctorstvnetwork.com/)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would suggest you back up your database and create a fresh install of the latest Wordpress version in a separate directory, using your existing database configuration. If this works, we know the data is good. You can reintroduce whatever customisations and plugins you use one by one until you find whatever is causing the issue. In future, run a `mysqldump` before you upgrade your CMS.

Comment: For the time being...  til you find a solution (read - Using the .Maintenance File):  http://cmswithwordpress.com/wordpress-maintenance-mode/  You may be able to just modify the existing .maintenance file to show the wordpress blog in maintenance mode

Answer (score 0):

Put your custom wp-config.php code before this:

```
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: I didn't add any custom code to the wp-config.php file. It has the original codes that worked a few days before the update. What i did do is commented out the reference to the admin bar require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/admin-bar.php' ); ... Then I tried logging in and it worked. Im not sure what effect commenting out that line of code will have, but no effect at all since Im technically using the prior version's guts. Thanks, for the advice. Let's see what happens.